# How to add class to the @Html.DropDownList?

Tags: c#, html, css, razor

Initially, the dropdown values are loaded from the model, now it needs to be loaded "static values". so I'm using the below type to load the dropdown  for this, I can't able to add the CSS-class. Need advice

```
 @Html.DropDownList("RoundOffInterval", new List<SelectListItem>
 {
     new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Roundoff Interval",Value=""},
     new SelectListItem{ Text="5",Value = "5" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="10", Value = "10" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="15", Value = "15" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="20", Value = "20" },
     new SelectListItem{ Text="30", Value = "30" }
})
```

Before I used the below type:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.RoundoffInterval, new SelectList(Model.RoundoffIntervalList, "Id", "Name"), "Select Roundoff Interval ", new { id = "RoundoffInterval", name = "RoundoffInterval", @class = "select2_demo_4 form-control" })
```

Comment: you didn't use @ for `id` and `name`

Comment: Yes! now it need to be loaded static for that i can't able to add class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Html.DropDownList(
"RoundOffInterval", 
 new List<SelectListItem>
        {
          new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Roundoff Interval",Value=""},
          new SelectListItem{ Text="5",Value = "5" },
          new SelectListItem{ Text="10", Value = "10" },
          new SelectListItem{ Text="15", Value = "15" },
          new SelectListItem{ Text="20", Value = "20" },
          new SelectListItem{ Text="30", Value = "30" },
       },
 new   {@class="select2_demo_4 form-control"})
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with this format

```
@Html.DropDownList("RoundOffInterval", new List<SelectListItem>
{
  new SelectListItem{ Text="Select Roundoff Interval",Value=""},
  new SelectListItem{ Text="5",Value = "5" },
  new SelectListItem{ Text="10", Value = "10" },
  new SelectListItem{ Text="15", Value = "15" },
  new SelectListItem{ Text="20", Value = "20" },
  new SelectListItem{ Text="30", Value = "30" }
}, htmlAttributes)
```

With `htmlAttributes` in your case is `new {@class="select2_demo_4 form-control"}`

Hope it help!